# What is "chained exception facility" in java?

Tags: java

i was reading about Throwable class from https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html but i was not able to understand the chained exception facility. so somebody can please help me in this.

Comment: I think above link could be detailed answer your question .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [Oracle doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/lang/chained-exceptions.html) says

```
Chained Exception Facility
```

> It is common for Java code to catch one exception and throw another

And an example here from [TutorialsPoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javaexamples/exception_chain.htm):

```
public class Main{
   public static void main (String args[])throws Exception { 
      int n = 20, result = 0;
      try { 
         result = n/0;
         System.out.println("The result is"+result);
      } catch(ArithmeticException ex) { 
         System.out.println ("Arithmetic exception occoured: "+ex);
         try { 
            throw new NumberFormatException(ex);
         } catch(NumberFormatException ex1) {
            System.out.println ("Chained exception thrown manually : "+ex1);
         }
      }
   }
}
```